# Problem with favicon and theme settings

Tags: files

I'm having an insane problem enabling shortcut icon in my theme. When I dpm `theme_get_setting('favicon')` and `theme_get_setting('toggle_favicon')` - I get null strings, even though in the `Shortcut icon settings` section of `admin/appearance/settings` I have the `favicon.ico` as the value of the path to custom icon (obviously, the default shortcut icon checkbox is blank).

This lead me to inspecting other themes setting pages (eg. `admin/appearance/settings/bartik`) and I found out that all of them display a full set of options while my theme has only one checkbox. See the attachments below:

**Bartik theme settings**
[image: Bartik theme settings]

**My theme settings**
[image: My theme settings]

Comparing the info files does not lead me to any findings.

The following is the info file of my theme:

```
name = SI 2012
description = SI Startup Theme
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x

features[] = main_menu

stylesheets[all][] = [...]
scripts[] = [...]

regions[offtop] = Off top
regions[header] = Header
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
regions[help] = Help
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Left sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Right sidebar
regions[footer] = Footer
regions[offbottom] = Off bottom
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what theme you are using. Is it a contributed or a custom theme, and you have made any custom changes to it.

Comment: It's my own one. I edited my question to provide the info file.

Comment: @@Artur: I have faced the similar problem. And as per your answer I have commented the features[] = favicon in the .info file. Now the favicon is reflecting. Did you find out how the features[] stuff affecting this ? It will be quite helpful if you share the same... Thanks....

Comment: @fero See [this post](http://drupal.org/node/171205) and make sure to read the features and settings sections, especially - how to initialize the setting. Seems like this is what I've been missing. Actually I did not use this lesson this time and let the things go as in my answer. A lesson to remember though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem solved. Removing the `features[]` line from the theme info kind of reset the settings page. I also read [this post](http://drupal.org/node/177868) about theme settings and providing default values. Problem solved, although I don't quite know why the `features[]` stuff affected the whole form. Will probably learn with time.

Answer (score 0):

features[] list the settings that should be available for your theme. In your case only the main menu settings should be present.

If you wanted eg. the favicon setting to be available too inside theme settings, you should add 'features[] = favicon' on a separate row in the .info file.

However the default behavior is to display all settings, so when you remove the 'features[] = main_menu' line from your .info-file the theme goes back to showing all settings.